# Windows XP Login Screen Changed

Tags: windows, windows-xp

My boss's computer is running Windwos XP Home Edition. Up to now, it has shown the big blue welcome screen which lists the accounts. However, today it is showing a window to log in. Any ideas why this is? The only change i'm aware of is that we removed the password for the account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an option set in User Accounts. When he was removing his password he may have turned off the Welcome Screen. Here is where to check;

1. Click Start, and then click `Control Panel`.
2. Double-click `User Accounts`.
3. Click `Change the way users log on or off`.
4. Check the `Use the Welcome screen` check box.